# Images showing up tiny in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using customtkinter (have tried with standard tkinter as well to rule it out) and having issues with displaying photos. I've tried `global`-ing the photo, I've tried `self.`-ing the photo, and I've tried appending the photo to a `global` list as well. Nothing so far has worked. The image appears in the pop-up window, but it's a few pixels wide and a few pixels tall. I've tried fooling with the `image.resize((width,height))` line, I've tried adjusting the size of the frame, I've tried not even using the frame at all. I cannot for the life of me scale this image to the proper size. Code is below.

```
import sys, os
import customtkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
#
currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
parentdir = os.path.dirname(currentdir)
sys.path.append(parentdir)
#
def init(top, gui, *args, **kwargs):
    global w, top_level, root
    w = gui
    top_level = top
    root = top
#
def destroy_window():
    # Function which closes the window.
    global top_level
    top_level.destroy()
    top_level = None
#
def vp_start_gui():
    '''Starting point when module is the main routine.'''
    global val, w, root
    root = tk.CTk()
    top = crc_main_window (root)
    init(root, top)
    root.mainloop()
#
w = None
def create_crc_main_window(rt, *args, **kwargs):
    '''Starting point when module is imported by another module.
       Correct form of call: 'create_crc_main_window(root, *args, **kwargs)' .'''
    global w, w_win, root
    #rt = root
    root = rt
    w = tk.CTkToplevel (root)
    top = crc_main_window (w)
    init(w, top, *args, **kwargs)
    return (w, top)
#
def destroy_crc_main_window():
    global w
    w.destroy()
    w = None
#
class crc_main_window:
    def __init__(self, top=None):
        '''This class configures and populates the toplevel window.
           top is the toplevel containing window.'''
        _bgcolor = '#d9d9d9'  # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _fgcolor = '#000000'  # X11 color: 'black'
        _compcolor = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana1color = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana2color = '#ececec' # Closest X11 color: 'gray92'
        # setting geometry and locking it in, as well as the title
        top.geometry("392x300+607+367")
        top.minsize(120, 1)
        top.maxsize(3604, 1061)
        top.resizable(0,  0)
        top.title("test window")
        top.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        # these were added later, and provides functionality to open additional windows to show reference information
        def max_power():
            self.max_power_top = tk.CTkToplevel(root)
            self.max_power_top.title("Max Power Transmission")
            self.max_power_top.geometry("372x351+607+367")
            self.max_power_top.resizable(0, 0)
            #
            self.max_frame = tk.CTkFrame(self.max_power_top)
            self.max_frame.place(x=3,y=3,height=345,width=366)
            #
            from PIL import ImageTk, Image
            self.image1 = Image.open(os.path.join(currentdir,'max_power_trans.PNG'))
            self.image1 = self.image1.resize((322, 301))
            self.image = tk.CTkImage(self.image1)
            self.label1 = tk.CTkLabel(self.max_frame,image=self.image)
            self.label1.place(x=0,y=0,width=322,height=301)
            self.label1.configure(text="")
        from tkinter import Menu
        menubar = Menu(top)
        top.config(menu=menubar)
        file_menu = Menu(menubar,tearoff=False)
        file_menu.add_command(label='Max Power Reference',command=max_power)
        file_menu.add_command(label='Exit',command=root.destroy)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File",menu=file_menu,underline=0)
#
if __name__ == '__main__':
    vp_start_gui()
```

Comment: @BryanOakley I added the additional starting functions as well as the __main__ if statement and the imports.

Comment: You need to specify the `size` option of `CTkImage()`, otherwise it will be 20x20 by default.  So use `self.image = tk.CTkImage(self.image1, size=(322,301))`.

Comment: @acw1668 I sometimes hate how simple Python fixes can be. This worked immediately, thank you so much!